# Convert some values of a list into float

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I've got a problem, my values in a list are of type real and I have to convert them into float.

The list looks as follows:

```
[{ 'O' : 15.2565, 'H' : 16, 'L' : 14, 'C' : 14.56, 'T' : '2017-12-30T13:30:00'},
{ 'O' : 14.56, 'H' : 17, 'L' : 13, 'C' : 16.654 'T' : '2017-12-30T13:35:00'},
etc]
```

The values of 'O' etc. are in real and need to be converted, how would I do that in Python as

```
float(x) for x in data
```

doesn't work for me.

Comment: there is no type `real` in python.

Comment: The 'O' values are already floats. Nothing to do.

Comment: It appears that the sample data you've shown here isn't representative of your actual data, since the values in question are already floats. Perhaps you have `int`s or `str`ings that you want to convert to `float`?

Comment: @Daniel but why does TA-Lib say that the type can't be real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of `dict` objects whose values (at least some of them) can be converted to `float`. A naive approach would be:

```
for dct in data:
  for k in dct:
    try:
      dct[k] = float(dct[k])
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
      pass
```

If you know beforehand which keys map to floatable values, you can use a comprehension for the questionable benefit of saving some lines. Note that this is a nested comprehension as the `dicts` need to be rebuild as well as the `list` around them:

```
data = [
    {k: float(v) if k in ('O', 'H', 'L', 'C') else v for k, v in dct.items()} 
    for dct in data
]
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what the OP wants, but if you're going to put this as an answer, you might as well make it `except (ValueError, TypeError)` to make it slightly more robust.

Comment: Ah OK thanks. A bit more to write but it works now thanks.